# overdetermined system of inequalities. violating least number of them.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

We are given a system of inequalities expressed in the following way:
$$ Ax> \underline{k}$$ where $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n,m(\mathbb{R})}$, with n>m, and $\underline{k}=(k,k,\ldots,k)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

In general, the system might or might not admit solutions. 
I would like to find a solution $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ that minimizes the number of violated inequalities. 
It's the first time I have to deal with this sort of discrete optimization problems and to be honest I have no idea where to start from.

If you could at least direct me a bit, that would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Ax\gt k$ is a difficult concept in optimization. Usually we deal with $Ax\ge k$. (If needed you can add a small number $\varepsilon>0$ to $k$; note also that solvers typically employ a feasibility tolerance, so $\varepsilon$ should be larger than that).

So, assume we have $Ax\ge k$. Next we can do
$$
\begin{align}
 \min\> & \sum_i \delta_i \\
 &\sum_j a_{i,j} x_j  \ge k - \delta_i M \\
 &\delta_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$

Here $M$ is a large enough number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very very helpful!