# How to solve an overdetermined system of linear inequalities?

Tags: linear-programming

I want to solve an overdetermined system of inequalities ($ax+by \ge c$). Specifically, I have $10$ linear functions of the form $ax+by$ that must be bigger than $c$ at a point $(x,y)$. But it is good to minimize the difference between $ax+by$ and $c$. I need a formula like [that (weighted overdetermined system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709602/when-solving-an-overdetermined-linear-system-is-it-possible-to-weight-the-influ).

I am lacking in mathematical knowledge. If you let me know the formulas and the concepts. I will solve my problem by using programming. Please help me.

[overdetermined system of inequalities. violating least number of them.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879038/overdetermined-system-of-inequalities-violating-least-number-of-them)

Comment: The [[[simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)]] has a variant to determine feasible solutions.

Comment: Look up [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Comment: Thanks, but it is difficult for me...